# How to avoid to avoid size limitations when deploying with AWS SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am using Lambda with nodeJs. The problem is that due to the `node_modules` dependencies I quite soon:

- Reach the maximum size of a lambda (3MB) that can still be edited in the online code editor (on the lambda page of the AWS Console).
- Reach the maximum size that I can deploy with the `sam deploy` command.

I also noticed on the AWS console the entire code base (with all of the functions and layers) is uploaded for each of the lambda functions, which is probably adding to the uploaded size counted towards the limits.

How can I avoid these limits? The library dependencies will likely to just grow over time. I tried to put all the npm dependencies in a separate [layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html), but that didn't help, as I still need to upload the functions and layers together from the command line, and they are both counted together towards both limits I think.

Comment: The SAM deployment package size limit is not 5 MB. That's the max length of a URL string.

Comment: @jarmod thanks. I took that out.

Comment: You shouldn't use the Lambda console for any significant project imo. The Lambda package size limits are hard limits. They're different (smaller) for ZIP files, and your actual deployment limit will include any layers too. Unless the Lambda service raises those limits, you'll have to find ways to reduce your total deployment size. Node is obviously a challenge here because half of the internet gets pulled into node_modules. Can you identify unused packages or large, minimally-used packages?

Comment: Agree with @jarmod that you should not do anything meaningful in the console editor. If you want to use a remote editor, you could try Cloud9 (which is ultimately what is being used in the Lambda console). As an alternative to a layer, Lambda supports EFS and you can store your node_modules in EFS, mount the EFS volume in your Lambda, and use the node_modules from the mount... Some details are found in this article [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/).

Comment: Develop your lambdas locally, test them, pack them in the deployment package (it has a size limit of 250 MB) and deploy using sam. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-invoke.html

Comment: Without know the structure (entry/outputs/buildspec/size/depends) of your project, it is very difficult to answer this properly. If the layers approach didn't work, why was that?